# How could i check the version of dojo installed in domino server?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

How could i check the version of dojo installed in domino server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default dojo version can be obtained by calling this:

```
com.ibm.xsp.context.DojoLibraryFactory.getDefaultLibrary().getVersion()
```

If You want to see all versions that can be found on server try this:

```
com.ibm.xsp.context.DojoLibraryFactory.getDojoLibraries()
```

If You want to check what version is current database using then You can do this:

```
com.ibm.commons.Platform.getInstance().getProperty("xsp.client.script.dojo.version")
```

Comment: Good tip. But this works only if the dojo library was not overwritten by CSJS.

Answer (score 3):

On 8.5.3 there are Dojo versions 1.5.1 and 1.6.1 installed. The question is which version is delivered by the server.

If you add this CSJS to your XPage you will get an alert containing current dojo version:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlockDojoVersion" value="dojo.addOnLoad( function(){ alert(dojo.version) } );" />
```